# Free shipping with flat rate shipping at magento 2

Tags: free-shipping, magento2.2.6

Can i make promotion for flat rate method? equal or greater than ... allow free shipping.

I have already do this with free shipping but both methods appear there. I have configured it many times at magento 1.9, but magento 2 resist....

I had also tried a custom module for shipping.

Any thinking about that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want under a certain amount to have specific shipping but over a specific amount to be free, I would recommend giving a look at Table Rates. These can accomplish specifically what you're looking to do.

MagePlaza has an excellent tutorial that will help you generate the table rates setup: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-table-rates-shipping-method-magento-2.html.

This is another helpful tutorial: https://www.humcommerce.com/tutorial/table-rates-shipping-magento-2/.

This method might be more what you're looking to do based on your description.

Answer (score 0):

what do you think about create Cart Price Rules to add free shipping method??

Magento Doc: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-free-shipping.html

Step 1: Enable Free Shipping

1. Enable Free Shipping in your store’s configuration.
2. Complete the free shipping settings for any carrier service that you want to use for free shipping.

Step 2: Create a Cart Price Rule

1. On the Admin sidebar, tap Marketing. Then under Promotions, choose Cart Price Rules.
2. Follow the steps below to set up the type of free shipping promotion that you want to offer.

Step 3: Complete the Labels

Complete Step 4 of the cart price rule instructions to enter any labels that appear during checkout.

Step 4: Save and Test the Rule

1. When complete, tap Save Rule.
2. Test the rule to make sure that it works correctly.
   Price rules are automatically processed with other system rules each night.When you create a new price rule, allow enough time for it to get into the system. Then, test the rule to make sure that it works correctly.